# R: Making a Transparent Plot

Tags: python, r

I am working with the R programming language.

Here is a transparent wire plot made in Python (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3d-wireframe-plotting-in-python-using-matplotlib/):

```
# importing modules
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import numpy 
from matplotlib import pyplot
 
# assigning coordinates    
a = numpy.linspace(-5, 5, 25)
b = numpy.linspace(-5, 5, 25)
x, y = numpy.meshgrid(a, b)
z = numpy.sin(numpy.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
 
# creating the visualization
fig = pyplot.figure()
wf = pyplot.axes(projection ='3d')
wf.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color ='green')
 
# displaying the visualization
wf.set_title('Example 2')
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

**My Question :** I am trying to recreate this kind of plot in R for a 2 dimensional Normal Distribution

I know how to plot a regular 2d normal distribution in R:

```
library(plotly)
library(MASS)
library(mvtnorm)


mu <- c(0, 0)  # Mean
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1), nrow=2)  


x <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)


z <- matrix(apply(grid, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma)), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y))


plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z, type = "surface") %>%
    add_trace(
        type = "surface",
        showscale = FALSE,
        opacity = 0.5,
        surfacecolor = matrix(rep(1, length(x) * length(y)), nrow=length(x), ncol=length(y)),
        colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("rgb(0,0,0)", "rgb(0,0,0)")),
        lighting = list(ambient = 1, diffuse = 0, fresnel = 0, specular = 0, roughness = 1)
    ) %>%
    layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'X1'),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'X2'),
                        zaxis = list(title = 'Density')))
```

[image]

But I don't know how to make this plot look "transparent wire mesh" style. The closest thing I could find was something like this: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/05/creating-surface-plots/

Can someone please show me how to do this? Note: The plot does not need to be 3D. 2D or 3D is fine.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I think this is possible?

```
library(plotly)

# Creating the data
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
grid <- expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
R <- sqrt(grid$x^2 + grid$y^2)
z <- sin(R)


fig <- plot_ly(x = ~grid$x, y = ~grid$y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = '#0066FF', width = 2)) %>%
    layout(title = "Wireframe Plot",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        yaxis = list(gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        zaxis = list(gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')),
           showlegend = FALSE)

# Print 
fig
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lattice package has a `wireframe()` function (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/lattice.pdf), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lattice)
library(mvtnorm)
set.seed(123)

mu <- c(0, 0)  # Mean
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.8, 0.8, 1), nrow=2)  


x <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-3, 3, length.out = 100)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma))

wireframe(z ~ x * y, data = grid, aspect = c(61 / 89, 0.3))
```

[image]

If you use fewer datapoints you can see the 'wires' better:

```r
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data = grid[1:2500,], aspect = c(10 / 10, 1))
```

[image]

---

Here is one potential approach for replicating your python example:

```r
x <- read_csv("/Users/jared/x.csv", col_names = NULL) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               values_to = "x")
#> Rows: 25 Columns: 25
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> dbl (25): X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, ...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
y <- read_csv("/Users/jared/y.csv", col_names = NULL) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               values_to = "y")
#> Rows: 25 Columns: 25
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> dbl (25): X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, ...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
z <- read_csv("/Users/jared/z.csv", col_names = NULL) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               values_to = "z")
#> Rows: 25 Columns: 25
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> dbl (25): X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, ...
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

python_data <- data.frame(x, y, z)
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data = python_data, aspect = c(10 / 10, 0.75),
          col.regions = "transparent", col = "green3")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to make the plot more transparent and lighter? so it looks more like the python visualization? thank you so much!

Comment: Edited my answer @stats_noob - let me know if this isn't what you're looking for

Comment: @ jared_mamrot: thank you so much for your answer! just a question - why are we using a .csv file here? can this be done without the csv file?

Comment: Oh! Yep - sorry that wasn't explained - I exported your python data to csv then read it into R to get the same plot as your first example

Comment: thank you so much for your clarifications! in my question, I wanted to make a 3d bell curve  (see my plotly example): I suppose your logic could be applied to this problem as well?

Comment: I wish it was possible to make this kind of wire mesh in the R version of plotly :( .... it seems possible in python: https://plotly.com/python/v3/3d-wireframe-plots/

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to make a bell curve, but not sure about plotly sorry. I'll look into it and get back to you if I find a solution. Glad this helped

Comment: @ jared: if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? Thank you so much! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657533/r-how-to-visualize-an-integral

Comment: Hey @stats_noob, I had a quick look - what you've done looks 'fine' to me, but I'm not an expert (it's been ~15 years since I studied differential/integral calculus). Hopefully someone with a maths background can advise you further. Good luck!