# R: How to Visualize an Integral

Tags: r, plotly

I am working with the R programming language.

Below, here is some R code (adapted from here: [R: Making a Transparent Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651034/r-making-a-transparent-plot)) for making a 3D Bell Curve (Gaussian/Normal Distribution):

```
library(plotly)
library(mvtnorm)  


mu <- c(0, 0)  
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)  

x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

grid$z <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma))

fig <- plot_ly(data = grid, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = '#0066FF', width = 2)) %>%
    layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')),
           showlegend = FALSE)

fig
```

[image]

**My Question:** I want to "shade in" the volume corresponding to the integral of this function (i.e. the bell curve) between the regions X = -1 to 1 and Y = -1 to 1.

Conceptually, I think this means that I need to select every point in this diagram and check if this point lies within the boundary (-1,1) and (-1,1) : If yes, then shade else no.

Here is my attempt to do this:

```
library(plotly)
library(mvtnorm)  

mu <- c(0, 0)  
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)  

x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

grid$z <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma))

grid$color <- '#0066FF'

grid$color[grid$x >= -1 & grid$x <= 1 & grid$y >= -1 & grid$y <= 1] <- 'red'

fig <- plot_ly(data = grid, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = ~color, width = 2)) %>%
    layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')),
           showlegend = FALSE)


fig
```

[image]

**But I am not sure if I have done this correctly. In general, is there a way to visualize the results of an integral within R?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://community.plotly.com/t/fill-volume-under-the-surface/64944/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a shaded volume to be placed under the surface, representing its integral. To do this, we need a 3D grid where the voxels are turned on or off according to whether they are inside or outside the volume of interest. This is the same basic principle as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657592/r-equivalent-of-python-add-volume-function/77691166#77691166)

For your example, we can set up the data as follows:

```r
library(mvtnorm)
library(plotly)

mu <- c(0, 0)  
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)  
grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(-5, 5, len = 50), y = seq(-5, 5, len = 50))

grid$z <- dmvnorm(grid, mu, Sigma)

grid3d <- expand.grid(x = seq(-1, 1, len = 100), 
                      y = seq(-1, 1, len = 100),
                      z = seq(0, 0.16, len = 100))

grid3d$value <- ifelse(grid3d[[3]] < dmvnorm(grid3d[1:2], mu, Sigma), 1, 0)
```

The plot would then be:

```r
plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(data = grid, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', 
            mode = 'lines', line = list(color = '#0066FF', width = 2),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  add_trace(type = "volume", data = grid3d, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z,
            value = ~value, opacity = 0.5, isomin = 0.1, showscale = FALSE,
            colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("red", "red"))) %>%
  layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
         scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                      yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                      zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')))
```

[image]