# R: Equivalent of Python "add_volume()" function?

Tags: python, r, plotly

I am working with the R programming language.

I found this tutorial/website over here that shows how to fill the volume under the surface in Python/Plotly (https://community.plotly.com/t/fill-volume-under-the-surface/64944/2):

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

f = lambda x,y: np.cos(x)+np.sin(y)+4

#surface
x, y = np.meshgrid( 
    np.linspace(-5, 5, 100),
    np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
)
z = f(x,y)

#patch of surface
lower_x, upper_x = -1, 2
lower_y, upper_y = -2, 4
int_x, int_y = np.meshgrid( 
    np.linspace(lower_x, upper_x, 50),
    np.linspace(lower_y, upper_y, 70)
)
int_z = f(int_x,int_y)

fig= go.Figure()
fig.add_surface(x=x[0], y=y[:, 0], z=z, showscale=False, 
                colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Pinkyl, opacity=0.6)
fig.add_surface(x=int_x[0],y=int_y[:, 0],z=int_z, showscale=False, colorscale=px.colors.sequential.Agsunset, opacity=1)
lower_z= 0

upper_z= int_z.max()

X, Y, Z = np.mgrid[lower_x:upper_x:50j, lower_y:upper_y:50j, lower_z:upper_z:75j]
vals = Z-f(X,Y)
fig.add_volume(x=X.flatten(), y=Y.flatten(), z=Z.flatten(), value= vals.flatten(),
                 surface_show=True, surface_count=2, 
                 colorscale=[[0, px.colors.sequential.Agsunset[4]],[1.0, px.colors.sequential.Agsunset[4]]],
                 showscale=False,
                 isomin=-upper_z, isomax=0) #isomin=-upper_z corresponds to z=f(x,y)-upper_z, and  isomax=0, to z=f(x,y)


fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, scene_zaxis_range=[0, upper_z+0.5],
                                                            scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.85, y=1.85, z=0.7))
```

**My Question:** I am trying to replicate this code in R.

Doing some research into this, I noticed that Plotly within R does not have an `add_volume()` function as in Python. I tried to attempt to work around this and find a new way to do this:

**Attempt 1:**

```
library(plotly)

f <- function(x, y) {
    cos(x) + sin(y) + 4
}

# Surface
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 100)
z <- outer(x, y, f)

# Patch of surface
lower_x <- -1
upper_x <- 2
lower_y <- -2
upper_y <- 4
int_x <- seq(lower_x, upper_x, length.out = 50)
int_y <- seq(lower_y, upper_y, length.out = 70)
int_z <- outer(int_x, int_y, f)

fig <- plot_ly() %>%
    add_surface(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, showscale = FALSE, opacity = 0.6, colors = c('#e31a1c', '#fb9a99')) %>%
    add_surface(x = ~int_x, y = ~int_y, z = ~int_z, showscale = FALSE, opacity = 1, colors = c('#a6cee3', '#1f78b4'))

fig <- layout(fig, scene = list(zaxis = list(range = c(0, max(int_z) + 0.5)), 
                                camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.85, y = 1.85, z = 0.7))))
fig
```

[image]

**Attempt 2: Identify the Area**

```
library(plotly)

f <- function(x, y) {
  cos(x) + sin(y) + 2
}

# surface
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 200)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 200)
z <- outer(x, y, f)

# patch of surface
lower_x <- -1
upper_x <- 2
lower_y <- -2
upper_y <- 4
int_x <- seq(lower_x, upper_x, length.out = 200)
int_y <- seq(lower_y, upper_y, length.out = 200)
int_z <- outer(int_x, int_y, f)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "surface", showscale = FALSE, opacity = 0.4) %>%
  add_surface(x = ~int_x, y = ~int_y, z = ~int_z, showscale = FALSE, opacity = 1) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)

fig
```

[image]

But so far, I can't get anything to work.
Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a volume trace using `add_trace(type = "volume")`. The input is different from the surface plot though. You need a regular 3D grid of points given as vectors of x, y and z co-ordinates, such as you might create with `expand.grid` in R. Each of these points must also have a value. Only values above the `isomin` argument and below the `isomax` argument get filled.

To fill a volume within an enclosed surface, you can simply calculate whether each 3D gridpoint should be filled or not.

Taking your own example, the set-up would be:

```r
f <- function(x, y) cos(x) + sin(y) + 2

x <- y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 200)
z <- outer(x, y, f)

xmin <- -1
xmax <- 2
ymin <- -2
ymax <- 4

volume_df <- expand.grid(x = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = 20 * (xmax - xmin)), 
                         y = seq(ymin, ymax, length.out = 20 * (ymax - ymin)),
                         z = seq(0, 4, length.out = 80))

volume_df$value <- with(volume_df, ifelse(z > f(x, y), 0, 1))
```

The plotting code is then straightforward:

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly(showscale = FALSE) %>% 
  add_surface(x = x, y = y, z = z, opacity = 0.4) %>%
  add_trace(type = "volume", data = volume_df,
            x = ~x,
            y = ~y,
            z = ~z,
            value = ~value,
            opacity = 0.2,
            isomin = 0.5,
            colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("red", "red")))
```

[image]

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: thank you so much for your answer! I will try your code today! Do you have any idea of your logic can be applied here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657533/r-how-to-visualize-an-integral thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve a similar effect by using add_surface() and adjusting the opacity to create a "volume" effect. Let's modify your Attempt 2 to demonstrate this:
library(plotly)

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  cos(x) + sin(y) + 2
}

# Surface
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 200)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 200)
z <- outer(x, y, f)

# Patch of surface
lower_x <- -1
upper_x <- 2
lower_y <- -2
upper_y <- 4
int_x <- seq(lower_x, upper_x, length.out = 200)
int_y <- seq(lower_y, upper_y, length.out = 200)
int_z <- outer(int_x, int_y, f)

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "surface", showscale = FALSE, opacity = 0.4) %>%
  add_surface(x = ~int_x, y = ~int_y, z = ~int_z, showscale = FALSE, opacity = 0.8) %>%
  layout(scene = list(
    zaxis = list(range = c(0, max(int_z) + 0.5)),
    camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.85, y = 1.85, z = 0.7))
  ), showlegend = FALSE)

fig
```

This code modifies the opacity of the added surface to create a filled volume effect. Adjust the opacity values for both surfaces (opacity = 0.4 and opacity = 0.8 in this example) to suit your desired visualization. This method essentially layers two surfaces to represent the volume underneath the surface. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, can you please take a screenshot of your answer? Thank you so much!