# R: How to Place Points Inside a Specific Region of a Plot

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following plot for a 3D bell curve (gaussian distribution):

```
library(plotly)
library(mvtnorm)  


mu <- c(0, 0)  
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)  

x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
y <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 50)
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)

grid$z <- apply(grid, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma))

fig <- plot_ly(data = grid, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(color = '#0066FF', width = 2)) %>%
    layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')),
           showlegend = FALSE)

fig
```

[image]

**My Question:** I want fill the inside of this plot with many red points between the x,y range (-1 to 1).

I tried to do this with the following code: Generate random points, calculate the z-value for each of these random points, and then place these points on the plot:

```
points <- data.frame(x = runif(100, -1, 1), y = runif(100, -1, 1))
points$z <- apply(points, 1, function(x) dmvnorm(x, mean=mu, sigma=Sigma))

fig <- fig %>%
    add_trace(data = points, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'markers',
              marker = list(color = 'red', size = 2))


fig <- fig %>%
    layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
           scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                        zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                     gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                     showbackground = TRUE,
                                     backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')),
           showlegend = FALSE)

fig
```

[image]

**But the points are appearing on the surface of the plot - I want the points to appear inside the plot. Is there any way to fix this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care about the distribution within the region?  If you want it to be uniform there, then you should sample x and y from the bivariate normal, and z uniformly from 0 to the density at x and y.  Reject any (x,y) pairs outside your desired range.

Comment: @ user2554330: thank you so much for your reply! no, I do not care about the distribution within the region. Thank you for your suggestion, I will start to work on this right now. If you have time, could you please post an answer where you attempt this as well and we can both compare solutions? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob isn't this effectively the same question I answered earlier?

Comment: @Allan Cameron: thank you so much for your answer! In the previous question, I was interested in filling the area as a solid ... here, I just want to place points within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate many random points in x, y, z space, then filter out those where the value of z exceeds the density at the given x, y point:

```r
library(mvtnorm)
library(plotly)

mu <- c(0, 0)  
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1), nrow=2)  
grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(-5, 5, len = 50), y = seq(-5, 5, len = 50))

grid$z <- dmvnorm(grid, mu, Sigma)

grid3d <- data.frame(x = runif(10000, -1, 1), 
                     y = runif(10000, -1, 1),
                     z = runif(10000, 0, 0.16))

grid3d <- grid3d[grid3d[[3]] < dmvnorm(grid3d[1:2], mu, Sigma),]
```

Resulting in:

```r
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z) %>%
  add_trace(data = grid3d, type = "scatter3d", mode = "marker",
            marker = list(size = 2, color = "red", opacity = 0.2)) %>%
  add_trace(data = grid, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = 'scatter3d', 
            mode = 'lines', line = list(color = '#0066FF', width = 2),
            showlegend = FALSE) %>%
  layout(title = "3D Normal Distribution Wireframe Plot",
         scene = list(xaxis = list(title = "X",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                      yaxis = list(title = "Y",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)'),
                      zaxis = list(title = "Z",
                                   gridcolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   zerolinecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                                   showbackground = TRUE,
                                   backgroundcolor = 'rgb(230, 230,230)')))
```

[image]

Personally, I think this gives a less aesthetic version than the volume plot, which I demonstrated in a very similar [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657533/r-how-to-visualize-an-integral/77692855#77692855)

Comment: Suggestion:  use `dmvnorm(mu, mean = mu, sigma = Sigma)` in place of the `0.16` magic upper limit for `z`, in case `Sigma` is changed to some other matrix.

Comment: @user2554330 that's a good point. I would probably define xmin xmax ymin and ymax for the same reason.